# Aircraft Identification: What single-engine, T-tail, commuter aircraft has a single prop but sounds like a jet?

Tags: aircraft-identification

My morning walk takes me past Hillsboro Airport, Portland, Oregon (HIO), and today I saw a rather strange plane landing.  It was a small commuter-size plane (6 passenger windows on each side), with a *single* surprisingly large propeller on the nose.  While landing it sounded much more like a jet than a prop.  The tail was "T" shaped and I thought I saw a jet exhaust at the back of the fuselage.

Was I imagining this, or does such a craft exist?

Sorry I didn't get a picture.

Comment: I edited to include the name of the airport. Of course, the IATA code uniquely identifies it but nobody outside the immediate area is going to know the IATA code of some small municipal airport.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sounds like a [Pilatus PC-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-12) to me.

[image: Chris Finney - Gallery page http://www.airliners.net/photo/Royal-Flying-Doctor/Pilatus-PC-12-45/0636290/L Photo http://cdn-www.airliners.net/aviation-photos/photos/0/9/2/0636290.jpg Originally found on wikipedia page as linked.]
<sup>image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-12), photographer: Chris Finney</sup>

Comment: That's definitely it, thanks. I guess I imagined the exhaust at the back since the turbine exhausts seem to be at the front behind the propeller.

Comment: What is the small pod at the right wing tip?

Comment: @mins that is the weather radar.

Comment: If this is not a PC-12, then this is a secret prototype of the [Cessna Denali](http://cessna.txtav.com/turboprop/denali) :-)

Comment: Could have been also a [TBM 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCATA_TBM), which is very similar.

Comment: @kebs No, it had more windows and the tail was definitely a "T" shape.

Comment: @kebs That's a new answer - avoid answering in comments.

Comment: @Criggie can you add the credits/source for that image you added?

Comment: @DeltaLima Done - its in the review queue now.

Comment: cool answer to a cool question.